# SQL Server find and replace specific word in all rows of specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `TblKit` that has columns `Id` and `Number`. `Id` is `primary key` of type `int` and `Number` is `varchar(50)`.

The data in the table looks like this:

```
Id     Number
---    ------
1      KIT001
2      KIT002 
3      DMB001
4      DM002
5      KIT003
```

I want to replace all the rows of `KIT%` with `CH` in the Number field. The desired output would look like:

```
Id     Number
---    ------
1      CH001
2      CH002 
3      DMB001
4      DM002
5      CH003
```

I have tried this update query:

```
UPDATE TblKit SET Number = REPLACE(Number, N'%KIT%', 'CH')
```

But it is not working.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Column name really had to be "number"?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
UPDATE tblKit
SET number = REPLACE(number, 'KIT', 'CH')
WHERE number like 'KIT%'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cac38/1)

or simply this if you are sure that you have no values like this `CKIT002`

```
UPDATE tblKit
SET number = REPLACE(number, 'KIT', 'CH')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/348e3/1)